# UnityVS auto format options

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unityvs

I started using UnityVS instead of monodevelop recently. Its working great with one exception:
every time I type in

```
void function(){
```

and press Enter key, it auto formats to:

```
void function()
{
    //code
}
```

when in actuality, i want it to format like:

```
void function(){
    //code
}
```

since I am more comfortable with this format. I tried looking for a way so that the editor will auto format to the second option but haven't been successful. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Tools>Options, then Text Editor>C#>Formatting>New Lines

Change the "New Line Options" for placing open braces after methods and whatever else you don't want braces on  new lines for.